# How to turn off SSL verification for Authlib client with HTTPX / Starlette?

Tags: authlib

I can't seem to find a way to make Authlib / HTTPS respect the self-signed certs no matter how hard I try, so I want to turn SSL verification off when making requests as the OAuth client. How can I do this? The `AUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT` looks like a variable that's only suitable for the server.

Comment: Hi, Did you figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

HTTPX session accepts a `verify` argument to disable SSL check. You can turn off SSL verification:

```
   client.get(...., verify=False)
```

Comment: You are right but your code should have been `async with httpx.AsyncClient(verify=False) as client:` because Client is the equivalent of `requests.Session`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using starlette client

```
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth

oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name='client',
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    server_metadata_url=well_known_configuration_endpoint,
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': scope,
        'verify': False # To disable SSL cert verification
    }
)
```